# Can we add a value to antd design form instance without having Form.Item wrapper for that property?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to add a value that i can get on form submit onFinish function. for example i have two buttons yes and no. when i click on them it should add {xyz:"yes"} for yes and {xyz:"no"} for clicking on no button.

Moreover i dont want to add <Form.Item name="xyz" /> in my

i have used form.setFieldsValue({xyz: value }) function but it doesnt assign values to form until there is Form.Item with name xyz defined for it.

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example using https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: here is an example where i want to add xyz property in my form by clicking on yes or no button https://codepen.io/iwebdev/pen/GRwyxKv?editors=0011

Comment: You can use `form.getFieldsValue(true)` or `form.getFieldValue('xyz')` to get the value for xyz. `onFinish` function will return values only for fields that are registered through Form.Item and fields are currently rendered in browser.

Comment: so it means that to register a field i must pass name in Form.Item without it i can't register or add any filed for Form ?

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same dilemma and the work around I came up with is I made another hidden `Form.Item` inside the form and manually set the value:

```
    <Form form={form}
         onFinish={() => form.setFieldValue("xyz", value)}> 
         <Form.Item noStyle name='xyz'> 
    </Form>
```

Comment: My workaround is similar to this but settings `initialValue={myValue}` in the `Form.Item` instead of calling `form.setFieldValue`.

Answer (score 0):

inside `<Form>` you must add property form like this

```
<Form form={form}>
```

and then you can use

```
form.setFieldsValue({xyz: value })
```